Install PHP on CENTOS 8.5.2111
I installed CENTOS 8.5.2111 and I am now trying to install PHP 7.2.24, but every install is giving this error:
Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/rempomd.xml: All mirrors were tried


CentoOS 8 has been EOL for years and the repos have been moved to the CentOS Vault URLs whereas you have the regular URLs on your system. Rather than dealing with all of that, install Alma Linux 8 or Rocky Linux 8 which are both binary compatible with CentOS (and Red Hat Enterprise Linux). PHP 7.2 is also EOL whereas PHP 7.4 is supported throughout the lifecycle of Alma Linux 8 and Rocky Linux 8 which is until 2029. Bottom line, it is best to avoid EOL/unsupported operating systems and software.

@NasirRiley You should consider including OEL 8 (or 9) as it is also binary compatible with REL and has a somewhat different support process.

CentOS 8 is a 5-year old distro and has hit its End Of Life at the end of 2021. So the repos have been moved to vault and changed URLs. You have to add this at the end of the /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo file:
[baseos]
name=CentOS Linux $releasever - BaseOS
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/BaseOS/$basearch/os/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial

[appstream]
name=CentOS Linux $releasever - AppStream
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/AppStream/$basearch/os/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial

[extras]
name=CentOS Linux $releasever - Extras
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/extras/$basearch/os/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial

[centosplus]
name=CentOS Linux $releasever - Plus
baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/os/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial

(source)
However, CentOS is a discontinued distro. You'd better off installing a living (and up-to-date) RHEL derivative such as Rocky Linux 9, Alma Linux 9, or Oracle Linux 9.
